# specify the number of columns in Crystal reports

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I'm trying to set Multiple columns in my crystal report detail section.i need at least three columns but it always gives me just two columns.how can i specify the number of columns

In my detail section i have checked "Format with multiple columns" and in the lay out tab
Detail size: width- 2.5
Gap between Details: horizontal - 0.5

This report is used as a subreport

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify the number of columns explicitly; you will need to adjust the `width` and `gap` properties to meet your needs.

Legend:

- PW: page width
- M: page margin
- C: # of columns
- CW: column width
- G: gap between columns

Use this formula as a guide:

`PW = 2M + C*CW + (C-1)*G`

Substituting your values:

`3 * 2.5" + 2 * 0.5" = 8.5"`

You haven't factored the margins in your calculation.  You can fix this by:

- setting your margins to 0 (not a good idea)
- decreasing your column size
- decreasing your gap size
- any combination of these